# Concordion - how can i set a value into a table?

Tags: concordion

At some stage in a concordion test I have, I set a value to some random number.

This value is passed along, and later on , I have some output. The output is "checked" using the concordion "table" setup, where i compare an output value to what I expect it to be.

The problem I have is that I would like to check against the random number mentioned above. When I *get* the random number, I can set it to something Concordion can store -

```
<span c:set="#prefixValue">Bob</span>
```

Well, you get the idea - I replace "Bob" with a getter for my value.

But when I try to use it:

```
<table c:execute="#actual = getValue(#report, #xpath)">
    <tr>
        <th>Field name</th>
        <th c:assertEquals="#actual">Value</th>
        <th c:set="#xpath">Xpath</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>UnrelatedValue</td>
        <td>SomeDeterminateValue</td>
        <td>theXpathForThisToCompareTo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>prefix</td>
        <td><span c:echo="#prefixValue" /></td>
        <td>differentXpathForThisToCompareTo</td>
    </tr>
```

The whole shebang grinds to a halt, complaining that

> "
>       Commands must be placed on  elements when using 'execute' or 'verifyRows' commands on a <table>.
>   "

How can I use a pre-determined value in a table in Concordion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh Lord! I didn't realise Concordion was going to get all rigid on me.

To fix, I had to alter the Concordion method I was using to be less stupidly rigid.

Following the general ideas here:
http://automatingsoftwaretesting.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/write-your-own-concordion-command-an-example-for-asserting/

I wrote this:

```
@Override
public void verify(CommandCall commandCall, Evaluator evaluator, ResultRecorder resultRecorder) {
    Object expected = evaluator.evaluate(commandCall.getChildren().get(0).getExpression());
    Object actual = evaluator.evaluate(commandCall.getExpression());

    Element element = setupTheGoshDarnElement(commandCall, expected);

    if (actual.equals(expected)) {
        resultRecorder.record(Result.SUCCESS);
        announceSuccess(element);
    } else {
        resultRecorder.record(Result.FAILURE);
        announceFailure(element, expected.toString(), actual);
    }
}

private Element setupTheGoshDarnElement(CommandCall commandCall, Object expected) {
    Element e = commandCall.getElement();
    e.appendText(expected.toString());
    return e;
}

private void announceFailure(Element element, String expected, Object actual) {
    listeners.announce().failureReported(new AssertFailureEvent(element, expected, actual));
}

private void announceSuccess(Element element) {
    listeners.announce().successReported(new AssertSuccessEvent(element));
}
```

And so made a new "evaluator" ~ the rest of the evaluator is identical to the AssertEqualsCommand, if you're wondering.

This neatly checks the element and evaluates. Why concordion didn't do this ~ it isn't rocket science at all ~ is beyond me!

NOTE that I still need to use the "expanded table" in my question to get this to work, the short-form table has it's own issues  with evaluating inner expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The specs aren't supposed to have random elements in them. They're supposed to contain a specific example or set of examples. Rather than using a random number, hardcode a particular value and then you can use it later on.

To tell the fixture about the hardcoded value you can do this:

```
<span c:execute="setPrefixValue(#TEXT)">Bob</span>
```

Then in the fixture:

```
public void setPrefixValue(String prefixValue) {
    // TODO: Whatever system configuration you need to do
}
```

If it isn't actually possible to set the value in your system under test, then use your fixture code to map between the hardcoded value and the actual random value.

```
public String getValue(String report, String xpath) {
    String value = report(report).get(xpath);
    if (value.equals(knownRandomValue)) {
        return hardcodedValue;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: interesting idea, in the end i just rolled my own comparator. Still don't understand why i cannot have a value i've saved elsewhere (out of the box, i mean)- seems pretty weak sauce to me.

Comment: It's against Concordion's general philosophy of "don't do anything fancy in the specs". The specs are intended to be like static documentation, not JSPs.